# selenium ide screenshot save fail

Tags: save, screenshot, selenium-ide

I need to be able to take a screenshot of a webpage and save it to a folder on my hard-drive. To do this I tried to use the captureEntirePageScreenshot, setting the folder I was to use as the target.

```
    <tr>
<td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
<td>C:\Users\.....\Desktop\test</td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
```

I get the following error when I tell it to execute. Note: the base URL on selenium and the webpage match.

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFileOutputStream.init]" nsresult: "0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986" data: no]. QueryInterface -> function QueryInterface() { [native code] }, message -> Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFileOutputStream.init], result -> 2152857621, name -> NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED, filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2986, columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986, inner -> null, data -> null, initialize -> function initialize() { [native code] }
```

If anyone can help me make sense of this and solve it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have and what version of the IDE? Did this just start happening? Did it work before? Has Firefox upgraded recently? Do you get the issue on other machines?

Comment: firefox: 22.0; Selenium:2.2.0; I do not know if this just started happening, or if my coworkers are experiencing similar problems, as I/we have not needed to save a screenshot before now. The most recent firefox upgrade was last month.

Comment: Correction: the most recent firefox upgrade we applied was done last month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it work for you or not because it work fine for me

```
       <tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/</td>
<td></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
<td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
<td>d:/title.png</td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: It didn't. I recieved a similar error message to the one above:

Comment: [error] Unexpected Exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) }[nsIFileOutputStream.init]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986" data: no].

Comment: message -> Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIFileOutputStream.init], QueryInterface -> function QueryInterface() { [native code] }, result -> 2147500037, name -> NS_ERROR_FAILURE, filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2986, columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986, inner -> null, data -> null, initialize -> function initialize() { [native code]

Comment: Sorry about splitting it up, but it was too long to post in just one comment.

Comment: @Skulgren - Go to selenium.org site and download new version of selenium ide   Please let me know which version of selenium ide did you use and version oF FF also

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm using Selenium 2.2.0, but am on Firefox 17.0.1, and the command below works for me.

```
captureEntirePageScreenshot | c:\selenium\test.jpg |
```

Note that it works with or without the file extension.  You might want to check with seleniumhq.org to see if there's a reported issue with that command in Firefox 22.

Klendathu

Comment: Worth a shot, but still no cigar. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the back slashes from \ to \\ in the file path.

```
<tr>
<td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
<td>C:\\Users\\.....\\Desktop\\test</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Hope that helps.